# Spring не видит XML файл

Tags: java, spring, maven

Есть некий файл spring-idol.xml, в котором лежат бины.

Однако при запуске программы, кидает Exception что нет такого файла, вот скрин:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvVxd.png

Comment: Меня что-то смущает `\ `  и `/ ` в пути к файлу (и `]` в конце пути в ошибке). Выложите конфигурацию где указываете пути к файлу и полный код ошибки.

Comment: А вы пробовали оставить только "spring-idol.xml"
Или же "classpath:test/test/spring-idol.xml"

Comment: Вообще все "ресурсные" файлы принято складывать в отдельную папочку (resources). resources кладут в main рядом с java. И скорее всего в переменной classpath у вас не определенна папка содержащая spring-idol.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Некомпилируемы файлы являются ресурсами и в Maven проекте должны находиться внутри директории recources а не java. Кроме того к ресурсам нельзя обращаться как к файлам. Иначе ваш проект перестанет работать из JAR файла. Обращайтесь к ресурсам используя метод `Class#getResourceAsStream()`

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-